# Python: OSC.py No callback registered to handle OSC-address

Tags: python, osc, max-msp-jitter

I hope someone can help me!
I'm getting this error when sending OSC messages:

```
OSCServer: No callback registered to handle OSC-address '/minibee/output/1'
```

I seem to have got a successful OSC server running, but it won't send out any data, and complains about the data it's receiving...

```
Created OSC listener at (0.0.0.0,57600) and OSC sender to (127.0.0.1,57120) and opened serial port at /dev/tty.usbserial-A800f7Tb. Now waiting for messages.
```

I have checked that the script is expecting this format:

OSC messages it listens to:

/minibee/output - iii..i - id, and as many 8bit integers as outputs (first PWM's then digital)

/minibee/custom - iii..i - id, and as many 8bit integers as the custom message requires

OSC messages it sends:

/minibee/info   - siii   - serial number, id, number of inputs, number of outputs

/minibee/data   - iff..f - id, and as many floats as inputs

Is anyone familiar with this and able to help me troubleshoot?  I'm using Max/MSP to send and receive OSC messages, but I don't think my problem is with Max.

Comment: *clarification:* so the problem was, that instead of adding arguments to the message you sent to the server, you added the values to the message path, thinking this is where arguments belong. (it took me a while to understand that)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if I understand correctly, a callback registered for

```
"/minibee/output"
```

will not be called for an OSC message with a path of

```
"/minibee/output/1"
```

or     "/minibee/output/anything_really"

so your handlers need to register for "/minibee/output" and then you get the integers in the arguments to the callback.