# Can I create OSC message handlers containing wildcards?

Tags: python, osc

I am trying to create an OSC msg handler, using pyosc, which can listen to incoming multitoggle messages from TouchOSC.

The multitoggle is a grid of toggleswitches. The incoming messages are in the form "/1/multitoggle1/5/8" or "/1/multitoggle1/x/y" where x and y are integers corresponding to the grid position.

server.addMsgHandler( "/1/multitoggle1/5/8", toggle_callback ) works fine but I need the 5 and the 8 to be arguments read in the handler so I can get at them without having to add a separate handler for each individual toggle.

s.addMsgHandler( "/1/multitoggle1/", toggle_callback ) does not seem to work.

It is a similar problem to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11309660/python-osc-py-no-callback-registered-to-handle-osc-address) but I can't implement the implied solution.

Comment: the problem you linked to in the end is different, in that he just sent a message with a wrong path to the server, while you want to handle a range of similar message paths with a single method/handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem and this was my solution:

```
for x in range(1,9):
    for y in range(1,6):
        s.addMsgHandler("/Channels/toggleChannels/"+`y`+"/"+`x`, toggleChannels)

def toggleChannels(addr,tags,data,source):
    split = addr.split("/")
    x = split.pop()
    y = split.pop()
```

I registered all handlers but used only one callback, worked great

Answer (score 0):

Or better yet, extracting things and preventing hardcoding:

```
# this is put into a config file for easy mod'ing
OSCPATH = {
    # Incoming OSC from the tracking subsys
    'ping': "/ping",
    'start': "/pf/started",
    'entry': "/pf/entry",
    'exit': "/pf/exit",
    'update': "/pf/update",
    'frame': "/pf/frame",
    'stop': "/pf/stopped",
    'set': "/pf/set/",
    'minx': "/pf/set/minx",
    'maxx': "/pf/set/maxx",
    'miny': "/pf/set/miny",
    'maxy': "/pf/set/maxy",
    'npeople': "/pf/set/npeople",
    # Outgoing OSC updates from the conductor
    'attribute': "/conducter/attribute",
    'rollcall': "/conducter/rollcall",
    'event': "/conducter/event",
    'conx': "/conducter/conx",
}


class OSCHandler(object):

    """Set up OSC server and other handlers."""

    def __init__(self, field):
        self.m_server = OSCServer( (OSCHOST, OSCPORT) )

        self.EVENTFUNC = {
            'ping': self.event_tracking_ping,
            'start': self.event_tracking_start,
            'stop': self.event_tracking_stop,
            'entry': self.event_tracking_entry,
            'exit': self.event_tracking_exit,
            'update': self.event_tracking_update,
            'frame': self.event_tracking_frame,
            'minx': self.event_tracking_set,
            'miny': self.event_tracking_set,
            'maxx': self.event_tracking_set,
            'maxy': self.event_tracking_set,
            'npeople': self.event_tracking_set,
        }

        for i in self.EVENTFUNC:
            self.m_server.addMsgHandler(OSCPATH[i], self.EVENTFUNC[i])
```

You'll see that several paths, including minx, miny, etc, map to the same function.  These use the path param to take specific actions to handle this data.

Answer (score 0):

OSC does support wildcards in the Address Pattern of Methods (OSC speak for what you call Handlers).

They work similar to windows or unix command-line file name wildcards, *not* like regular expressions. For details, check out *OSC Message Dispatching and Pattern Matching* in the [OSC 1.0 specifications](http://opensoundcontrol.org/spec-1_0).

In your example, you could define an address pattern *"/1/multitoggle1/*/*"*,
which would allow you to receive *"/1/multitoggle1/5/8"* and similar messages.