# Python-OSC wildcards in address

Tags: python, wildcard, osc

I found the topic [OSC message handlers with wildcards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19235302/can-i-create-osc-message-handlers-containing-wildcards) which is nearly about the same topic like mine. I want to have a generic handler instead of 8 handlers for 8 addresses. 
The code snippet shows the call of dispatcher 1...8 and the general one and the two handlers.

```
# dispatcher.map("/presets/1", preset_handler_1, preset01)
# dispatcher.map("/presets/2", preset_handler_2, preset02)
# dispatcher.map("/presets/3", preset_handler_3, preset03)
# dispatcher.map("/presets/4", preset_handler_4, preset04)
# dispatcher.map("/presets/5", preset_handler_5, preset05)
# dispatcher.map("/presets/6", preset_handler_6, preset06)
# dispatcher.map("/presets/7", preset_handler_7, preset07)
# dispatcher.map("/presets/8", preset_handler_8, preset08)
dispatcher.map("/presets/*", preset_handler, activePreset)

def preset_handler_8(unused_addr, args, val):
  if (val==1):
    print (args[0],"active")
    activePreset=8

def preset_handler(addr, args, val):
  print("phNDLER active")
  if (val==1):
    PRINT("HANDLER ACTIVE")
    preset_num=str(addr[-1])
    print (preset_num)
    activePreset=preset_num
```

Seems like I can only implement a wildcard into my OSC message to trigger more than one handler but not vice versa. 
Any chance to use wildcards in the handler call anyway?
Cheers Stefan

Answer (score 0):

I was wanting the same thing, so just created a pull request for python-osc.  Try my fork and let me know if it works for you:
https://github.com/jsheedy/python-osc

Comment: Your python-osc is what I am using.
Let me explain more precise: I do not want to define a handler for each preset call (means each address which is like "/Presets/..."
I would like one handler to be called and within this handler I want to do the preset specific things. So it is the opposite of your implementation. I found that if I have an address with a wildcard in my OSC layout every handler will be called. So is there any chance to have it vice versa or do I need a handler for each preset in my case?
BTW: Do you have any documentation to your OSC implementation?

Comment: The wildcard handler got merged in so now you can use the main project created by attwad: https://github.com/attwad/python-osc.  You can now accomplish the goal outlined in your question:  dispatcher.map("/presets/*", preset_handler, activePreset)
The README has enough information to get going, other than that the code is nicely readable for more documentation.